# Python 2.7 and blobkeys: how to return the filename instead of the url?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Very new to Python/Google App Engine and just trying to work my way around a pretty massive application. This is what I currently have:

```
file_keys = self.request.get_all('blobKey').filename        
file_links = []

for key in file_keys:
    file_links.append('https://www.mysite.com/admin/downloads/%s' % key)
```

This will return something similar to this:

*https://www.mysite.com/admin/downloads/4NLNpXrzZ0vjOZcOPzZpiQVoASeSXlZukbq0AMyFlmGYDhNZrWaRASBxL8TC6gjw*

How would I go about returning just the file name? (It's a form where you enter some information and provide a file, and I would like to return that specific file's filename in the email sent out instead of the generated URL).

I would think `filename` would work as shown here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass

But have not had any luck with that.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: The above code doesn't "return" anything, nor does it work because the indentation is wrong. Could you fix it and amend your description to match?

Comment: A blobstore filename is not unique. If you upload a file multiple times a new version of the file will be saved in the blobstore. Google cloud storage uses unique filenames, which can be addressed using a filename like url.

Comment: @voscausa You say a blobstore filename is not unique: so you're saying what I am trying to accomplish is not possible? Just a little confused; I apologize for the novice questions.

Comment: NO. I only say you cannot use a filename to address a blob in the blobstore. You need a blobkey. This also means you can have blobs with the same filename. This happens when you opload a file multiple times to the blobstore, Google Cloud Storage uses unique filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
file_keys = self.request.get_all('blobKey')     
blob_info_list = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(file_keys)
file_info_list = []
for blob in blob_info_list:
    info = {"file_name":blob.filename, "key":blob.key()}
    file_info_list.append(info)

template_dict = { 'file_info_list':file_info_list}
```